# FFMPEG: Generate 7.1 channel audio file with the longest time of input file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I want to use ffmpeg to generate 7.1 channel audio file from 8 different audio files.
But I found the output file's duration is decided by the input file with shortest duration.
I didn't find any parameter to auto-pad the shorter audio file or choose the longest duration as final duration.

I already have seen the offlical document as below.
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation
But nothing is helpful.

This is the command I use right now:

```
ffmpeg -i fl.wav -i fr.wav -i fc.wav -i lfe.wav -i bl.wav -i bl.wav -i sl.wav -i sr.wav -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a][4:a][5:a][6:a][7:a]join=inputs=8:channel_layout=7.1[a]" -map "[a]" output.wav
```

Comment: Get durations with `ffprobe`, pad audio with [apad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#apad) filter, then concat.

Comment: Thank you for response.
I know this, but I still prefer auto-padding when generate 7.1 channel file.

Comment: In FFMPEG's AudioChannelManipulation page, they say "With amerge all inputs must have the same sample rate and format. If inputs do not have the same duration the output will stop with the shortest."
So, I think maybe there exists a parameter to align the duration to the longest one.

Comment: There is no such option unfortunately.

Comment: Do you know how to pad the file to the duration I want? ex: The original file is 3 mins and I want to pad it to 5 mins.

Comment: Instead of ffprobe, can I use the ffmpeg to output the duration ?

Comment: Why do you not want to use `ffprobe`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Find input with longest duration:

   ```
   ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 input.wav
   ```
2. Add [apad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#apad) filter to all other inputs:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i fl.wav -i fr.wav -i fc.wav -i lfe.wav -i bl.wav -i bl.wav -i sl.wav -i sr.wav -filter_complex "[0:a]apad[a0];[1:a]apad[a1];[2:a]apad[a2];[3:a]apad[a3];[4:a]apad[a4];[5:a]apad[a5];[7:a]apad[a7];[a0][a1][a2][a3][a4][a5][6][a7]join=inputs=8:channel_layout=7.1[a]" -map "[a]" output.wav
   ```